# Set cellDelegate using generic

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics, swift3

Hi guys how are you? Hope you guys are fine.

I need a little help and i thank you in advance.

I have a custom delegate in my custom cell, like this:

```
protocol customTableViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func buttonPressed(customCell: customTableViewCell)
}
```

and i have a extension to set up the cell in table view, like this:

```
extension UITableView {
    func layoutTemplateCell<T: UIViewController>(indexPath: IndexPath, viewController: T.Type) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()

                switch template {
                case customCell:
                    let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customTableViewCell.identifier) as! customTableViewCell
                    cell.delegate = viewController.self
                    return cell
                default:
                    break
                }
            return cell
        }
}
```

but i'm getting a error in the cell.delegate "cannot assign value of type T.type to type customTableViewCellDelegate?"

i don't know how to use generic properly and i don't how to fix this error.

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you for the time to read this and have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign the view controller's class to the delegate property, not the view controller instance. What you want is:

```
cell.delegate = viewController
```

I don't understand why you are using generics though.  You can just use the protocol:

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func buttonPressed(customCell: UITableViewCell)
}

extension UITableView {
    func layoutTemplateCell(indexPath: IndexPath, viewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()

                switch template {
                case customCell:
                    let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customTableViewCell.identifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
                    cell.delegate = viewController
                    return cell
                default:
                    break
                }
            return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i using generics because i want to use more the one viewController for the extension. Imagine that all viewController that have tableView is going to use the same extension.

Comment: There is still no need to use generics. The layout function doesn't care; all it need to know is that it has something that conforms to the protocol

Comment: hi Paul, it only works because you are using one viewController like this 
func layoutTemplateCell(indexPath: IndexPath, viewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate) -> UITableViewCell
but i want to use with multiple viewController so i have to do something like this
func layoutTemplateCell(indexPath: IndexPath, viewController: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell
and when i do i have the same error

Comment: No, any view controller that you pass to this function *must* conform to the protocol. If you wanted to use UIViewController as the parameter type then you could conditionally downcast to `CustomTableViewCellDelegate` and only assign the delegate property of the downcast succeeds. There is nothing that you are trying to do here that needs generics.

Comment: Paul thank you man, i understand what you said and change my code putting the cast on the delegate and worked! thanks a lot!!